# This function how to use switch case

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in PHP and JS. This function use to get only one vales.
In my program dept1 values are 5 and 1st value select **onchange** in **1**, **2nd** select **onchange** in **2**, **3rd** value select **onchange** in **3**. so any idea to give code for switch case.

```
   <script> 
    function deptchange()
     {
        var x = document.getElementById("dept1").value;
        document.getElementById("dept2").value =  2;
      }
   </script>

    <input class="form-last-name form-control"  id= 'dept1'
    onchange="deptchange()" list="dept" value='<?php echo $dept;  ?>' name="department"/>

 <datalist id="dept">
 <option>
  <?php 
  include 'dblayer.php';
   $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT department FROM department");
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
     {
       echo "<option value='". $row['department']."'>".$row['department'] .'</option>';
         }
         ?>
        </option>
        </datalist>
   <input type="hidden" id='dept2' value=' 'class="form-first-name form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` with `push`, So after finished your 5 selection all 5 values push to values array.

```
<script> 
var values = [];
function deptchange()
{
   values.push(document.getElementById("dept1").value);
}
</script>
```

To get the stored elements from array.

```
var firstElement = values[0];
```

Comment: values all in lists. So how to get values. this is one field only. If u don't mine how to get values code write me

Comment: dept1 is one filed and then list of values.

Comment: can you send me that code. This is like departments HR, SALES, SYS ADMIN these values any one select then store 1 or 2 or 3. How to write this code

Comment: This is not working and not get value
values[0] mean like value[HR] or what?

Comment: @ Jarchanthan Ratnakuma update code please correct function code give me

Comment: post your code fiddle and share link to actually get to know whats your problem is?  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sarathi1990/uzeceuhy/2/

can u understand my query. Just see the link and get my code

Comment: sure i will give you. But i want to update query only recuse
How to share my folder

Comment: got it @Jarachanthan Ratnakumar

Comment: please any one say give solution or i will try another way

Answer (score 0):

datalist's option should have value attribute. and there is no need to put closing tag. it's different from select's option.

```
<datalist id="dept">
     <?php 
        include 'dblayer.php';
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT department FROM department");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<option value='". $row['department']."'>';
          }
     ?>
</datalist>
```